# EPiServer: Can I set a dynamic property from code-behind?

Tags: asp.net, episerver

I tried to set it as a normal page-property, but no luck.

Guess I could use the DynamicProperty class but I really want to avoid this because of the no-cache issue.

Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the only way to do this is with the DynamicProperty class. If you look at the documentation on the indexer property on the [PageData](http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms6/html/T_EPiServer_Core_PageData.htm) object it says:

> Note! Using this indexer will use the Pre and Post handlers for property lookup. I e return values are not guaranteed to belong to the page, but may be dynamic properties, "fetch-data-from"-data etc. To get data guaranteed to belong to this page, use the GetValueand SetValue methods.
>
> Also note that setting values with this indexer will only set values that acually belong to the page, i e you may get a valid value by reading from the indexer, but trying to set a new value for the same index may yield an exception since the value does not exist in the page.

You will need to use the DynamicProperty class:

```
DynamicProperty myDynProp = DynamicProperty.Load(CurrentPage.PageLink, "PropertyName");
myDynProp.PropertyValue.Value = "new value";
myDynProp.Save();
```

Alternatively, you could circumvent the Dynamic Property using an idea Joel discusses [here](http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/working-with-dynamic-properties-and-page-type-builder)